# Running composer update with docksal returns lack of memory

Tags: windows, macos, docker, boot2docker

When I run `composer update` in [Docksal bash](https://github.com/docksal/docksal) (or `fin run composer update`) I'm faced with:

> The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap configured
>
> Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details

How do I make composer work?

Answer (score 2):

Default Docksal virtual machine has 1GB (1024MB) of RAM. Drupal 8 tools like composer or twig debugger often require more that that.

You can set Docksal VM to have more RAM either manually in Virtual Box UI or using fin:

```
fin vm ram 2048
```

Comment: At this point default RAM is 2GB, but Composer sometimes requires up to that amount (e.g. for Acquia BLT). The solution is the same, just increase vm ram with `fin vm ram 4096` if you use VirtualBox, or increase it in UI in case of Docker Desktop.